# Is this a valid way of proving this series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Take the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k+k}$

Since I use the Cauchy Criterion, for $n, m$ ∈ ℕ with $m > n$, define:

$S_{m,n} = \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k+k}$

Here is my (shortened) proof:

If $n$ and $m$ are odd then

- $S_{m,n} = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}+n+1} - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}+n+2}$) + ... + ($\frac{1}{2^{m-1}+m-1} - \frac{1}{2^{m}+m}$)

All terms are positive because the series is decreasing and in each bracket, the next term is being taken away from the previous one, so $S_{m,n} \geq 0$ (This explanation feels horrible, please correct me on how to properly word this)

- $S$<sub>$n,m$</sub> = $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}+n+1}$ + ($-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}+n+2} + \frac{1}{2^{n+3}+n+3}$) + ... + ($-\frac{1}{2^{m-2}+m-2} + \frac{1}{2^{m-1}+m-1}$) - $\frac{1}{2^{m}+m}$

All brackets are negative in addition to the final term of the series being negative, so $S_{m,n} \leq\frac{1}{2^{n+1}+n+1}$

Note, this is just the case when $n$ and $m$ are odd and I know I'd have to do the rest of the cases. I just wanted to make sure my general logic was sound

So $0 \leq S_{m,n} \leq\frac{1}{2^{n+1}+n+1}$

At the end of all cases, you would get:

- $\vert S_{m,n}\vert \leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}+n+1}$

Now time to finish it off and apply the Cauchy Criterion. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, let $N  = \lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil$.

Then we have for all $m > n > N$:

- $\vert S_{m,n}\vert\leq\frac{1}{2^{n+1}+n+1}$ < $\frac{1}{N}\leq\varepsilon$

So the series exists and it converges. Proof done? This is my first module on real analysis so please understand that I'm having difficulty with the general topic. Thank you.

Comment: 1. "the series exists and it diverges" doesn't make sense to me. 2. You heard of the alternating series test?

Comment: @stange sorry I meant it converges. And yes I have but I wanted to know if this way of applying the cauchy criterion was correct.

Comment: Yes, that's correct (please note you have a typo in signs in last bracket in second grouping for $S_{n, m}$). To justifty $S_{n,m} \geq 0$, you can say that it's sum of non-negative terms. And you can make things simpler by applying essentially comparison test, and saying that $|S_{n, m}| \leq \sum_{k=n}^m \frac{1}{2^k + k} \leq \sum_{k=n}^m \frac{1}{2^k}$.

Comment: @mihaild Thank you for your feedback. Looking at the comparison test, mine has the alternative sign, wouldn't that make the equality you stated not true?

Comment: We have $|S_{n,m}| \leq \sum_{k=n}^m |a_k|$ regardless of signs of $a_k$ (from triangle inequality).

Comment: The series is absolutely convergent by comparison with $\frac 1 {2^{k}}$.